# Python--Need to Read and find data, and copy a file to another location (beginner)

Tags: python, copy

I'm a beginner at this, and not really sure how to accomplish it. Basically, I need to be able to open a file (user inputs the name, and a starting and ending address). I need to be able to search through the file and find the starting address, and only copy the information from the given starting address to the ending address, but after looking through multiple examples on this site, I can't seem to get it to function. My code for now (with many tests to make sure it can actually run is):

```
import pickle, pprint

def openFileandRead():

    filename = raw_input("Please enter your filename:\n")
    openedFile = open(filename, "rb")
    startAddress = raw_input("From the EEPROM file, enter 'Start Address':\n")
    endAddress = raw_input("From the EEPROM file, enter 'End Address':\n")

    with open(filename, 'rb') as searchfile:
        for line in searchfile:
            if 'searchphrase' in line:
                print line

    #this does nothing...but i'm not sure why...

    with openedFile as fp:
        for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
            process_line(line)
            print line
    #nothing as well...     

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
    #more nothing


    newFilename = '"'+ filename + '"'
    print newFilename
    print openedFile.tell
    print openedFile.name
    print openedFile.mode
    print openedFile.softspace
    print openedFile.encoding
    print type(openedFile)

    x = openedFile.readline()
    for line in x:
        return x
        print x
    #again, nothing
```

Sorry if I don't need a lot of it...but I don't understand why nothing works minus the print statements. I'm barely sure how to actually search for the start/end address to use them to copy that information either. Any help would be useful, thanks :)

Comment: "#this does nothing...but i'm not sure why..." What have you done to debug this code? Did you check line by line if the data is really there? Example data is necessary in order to comment on this issue!

Comment: I tried to check line by line...by putting print statements in between, but it doesn't seem to see those lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's look through your code:

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter your filename:\n")
openedFile = open(filename, "rb")
startAddress = raw_input("From the EEPROM file, enter 'Start Address':\n")
endAddress = raw_input("From the EEPROM file, enter 'End Address':\n")
```

This is *mostly* correct, but keep in mind:

- You don't need the `'\n'` in the `raw_input()` calls unless you really want the user input to be on the next line. (Just a nitpick.)
- `startAddress` and `endAddress` should really be integers, right? (or, well, naturals, I suppose.) So you need to use `int` to convert them to numbers.

Next section:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'searchphrase' in line:
            print line
```

In the previous section of code, your goal seems to be to extract a slice of the file's contents. However, in this part, you're iterating through each line and checking if `'searchphrase'` is present. If so, you're printing the line. So this code isn't helping you achieve your goal, is it? The next `with` block is calling an unknown function, so I can't help there. The final block should print each line - does your file even have content?

To get to a particular part of the file, you want to use [`file.seek()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek). See the linked Python documentation.

Finally, in your last loop:

```
x = openedFile.readline()
    for line in x:
        return x
        print x
```

You're reading one line, then iterating through each character in that line, then returning the first character, ending your function. You may not want that `return` there.

Comment: Makes sense...
One more auestion though, for the startAddress/endAddress they're addresses in memory given like "80BB3" and "80540"....so do I still need to convert to numbers?

Comment: @Jakute, yes. Try this: `int('80BB3', base=16)`.